# Create hourly dateseries with group by few columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I have a table df_in with 4 columns as shown below.I am getting error while trying to create dateseries on hourly basis with group by few columns.

```
Gender = c("Male","Female")
Sec = c("AA","BB")
min_date = c("12/1/2018","12/9/2018")
max_date = c("12/3/2018","12/10/2018")
    
df_in = data.frame(Gender,Sec,min_date,max_date)
```

for 1st row number of rows will be 72  (3 days * 24 hours) and for 2nd row 48 rows (2 days * 24 hours)

df_out will look like

[image]

I have tried with below code

```
df_out = df_in %>% group_by(Gender, Sec) %>% mutate (DateSeries = seq(as.POSIXct(min_date), as.POSIXct(max_date), by="hour"))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... and your error is?

Comment: Error : Error: Column `DateSeries` must be length 1 (the group size), not 721

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this produce what you need?

```
df_in %>% 
  group_by(Gender, Sec) %>% 
  expand(
    nesting(Gender,Sec), 
    DateSeries = seq(as.POSIXct(min_date), as.POSIXct(max_date), by="hour")
  )
# A tibble: 2,162 x 3
# Groups:   Gender, Sec [2]
   Gender Sec   DateSeries         
   <chr>  <chr> <dttm>             
 1 Female BB    0012-09-20 00:00:00
 2 Female BB    0012-09-20 01:00:00
 3 Female BB    0012-09-20 02:00:00
 4 Female BB    0012-09-20 03:00:00
 5 Female BB    0012-09-20 04:00:00
 6 Female BB    0012-09-20 05:00:00
 7 Female BB    0012-09-20 06:00:00
 8 Female BB    0012-09-20 07:00:00
 9 Female BB    0012-09-20 08:00:00
10 Female BB    0012-09-20 09:00:00
# ... with 2,152 more rows
```

Your first effort with `mutate` won't work because you're trying to add a 721 element vector to a data frame with only one row.  `expand` is the function you need: it creates and "all possible combinations" version of its inputs.

Comment: Code is running but may be version issue (currently using R - 4.0.3)..

Comment: below are the details nrow(df_out)
4324
str(df_in)
'data.frame':     2 obs. of  4 variables:
  $ Gender  : chr  "Male" "Female"
$ Sec     : chr  "AA" "BB"
$ min_date: chr  "12/1/2018" "12/9/2018"
$ max_date: chr  "12/3/2018" "12/10/2018"

Comment: above details are shown after running the code